# Traversing a grid

Tags: board-games

I'm wondering if there's a way to check if every square of a board can be visited such that every time you move to a new square, it can't be in the same row, column, or diagonal as the previous square.  If it can, how could I find a sequence of squares that works?  I've ascertained that it can't be done if $\text{rows} + \text{columns} \leq 6$.   It kind of reminds me of the n queens problem, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Uh... It seems like you are doing [Google Code Jam](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051635), which is currently running....

Comment: This post has been locked, as it is taken from an ongoing contest. For more information see our policy on **[Questions from Ongoing Contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests/1675)**.
It will be eligible to be unlocked when the contest ends, 4/28/19.

Comment: (And now unlocked.)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, a Knight's Tour would satisfy your restrictions.  Each knight move ends up on a different row and column from the starting point, and is not on a diagonal from it.  This is more restrictive than necessary for your purposes, but at least sets a base case that you know is possible.

From the Wikipedia page for [Knight's Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour):

> Schwenk proved that for any $m \times n$ board with $m \le n$, a closed knight's tour is always possible unless one or more of these three conditions are met:
>
> - $m$ and $n$ are both odd
> - $m = 1, 2,$ or $4$
> - $m = 3$ and $n = 1, 2, 3, 5$ or $6$
>
> Cull et al. and Conrad et al. proved that on any rectangular board whose smaller dimension is at least 5, there is a (possibly open) knight's tour.

So those would give some minimal constraints for which a Knight's Tour is provably possible.